# Command line Curl to Php curl code Issue

Tags: php, curl

Command line Curl which is working properly is :

```
curl --data username=ekansh&domain=siteURL&password=mypass
http://siteURL:8090/add-user -k -v -u apiuser:XXXXXXX
```

And i have tried below code for convert it in PHP CURL CODE:

```
    $fields = array('domain' => 'SiteUrl:8090','password' => 'mypass','username' => 'Ekansh');

    $data=array(CURLOPT_POST => 1,CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,CURLOPT_URL =>
    'SiteUrl:8090/add-user ',CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 
1,CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE =>
    1,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER =>
 FALSE,CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'apiuser:XXXXXXX',CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>TRUE);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$data);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

But above code is not working. what i am done wrong in code?

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get any error messages? If so, which?

Comment: I am printing response ($result) from above URl but not receiving anything

Comment: the parameter to data should be inside single quote.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im which part are you talking about?

Comment: The curl command. & will pass whole command to background.  Any parameter contains `&` should be quoted.

Comment: yes i knew that but my issue is with PHP code in second block

Comment: well... what is your issue? and do you want to accomplish with the result? have you tried if a quick and dirty `$result = shell_exec('curl --data username=ekansh&domain=siteURL&password=mypass http://siteURL:8090/add-user -k -v -u apiuser:XXXXXXX')` has the desired result?

Comment: i have tried this code curl --data 'username=ekansh&domain=siteURL&password=mypass' https://siteURL:8090/add-user -k -v -u 'apiuser:XXXXXXX' from command line and getting the desired result but when i am trying to run this code to Php curl code as mention above, no response is  generated @Soundz